# Show list of Child Post in Parent Post

Tags: child-pages

I have created custom post type. I have posted a parent post and it has a few child posts as well.

On the Parent post, I want to show its children posts.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

This would do it..

```
function get_child_pages() {
    global $post;
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
            //Child pages
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
     echo 'Sorry, No posts found.';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```